# Create WCF service like the one that I need to consume

Tags: wcf, simulate

I have a **WCF Service** expose for me in my Test environment that I need to consume. In order to test my client code in my local environment I wish to create a **WCF service that behave like this service.** My question is, is it possible to create that kind of simulator (Local WCF Service) from all the code that I have with the same binding, behavior etc. like the service that expose to me in my Test env? (I have: WSDL's files + XSD's, *.cs + output.config that generated by SvcUtil tool)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like SOAP UI?

http://www.soapui.org/
http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/functional-testing.html

Comment: No. I wish to create a WCF service that behave like this service.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest for you would probably be to make a copy of your WCF service code, and remove all implementation and replace it with your logic. In case you didn't had access to the service code I would say use svcutil.exe to generate the data contract classes and then manually build a WCF server that uses these contracts and has the right binding.